# Determine condition in list of strings

Tags: python, python-3.4

I'm used to C# and writing a python script. I want to determine if any of the strings in the list contain the string "ERROR".

In C# I would do something like this:

```
string myMatch = "ERROR";
List<string> myList = new List<string>();
bool matches = myList.Any(x => x.Contains(myMatch));
```

My attempt in python tells returns `TRUE` even though the list contains strings that contain the word `ERROR`.

```
def isGood (linesForItem):
    result = True;
    if 'ERROR' in linesForItem:
        result = False
    return result
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sounds like you mean:

```
def isGood(linesForItem):
    result = True
    if any('ERROR' in line for line in linesForItem):
        result = False
    return result
```

or more simply:

```
def isGood(linesForItem):
    return not any('ERROR' in line for line in linesForItem)
```

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes the boring solution is also one of the fastest...

```
def isGood(linesForItem):
    for line in linesForItem:
        if "ERROR" in line:
            return False
    return True
```

This will also stop as soon as it finds a match.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have to check whether the `'ERROR'` substring for each element in the list. Currently you just check whether that string is in the array. This line will get you the answer.

```
any(map(lambda o: 'ERROR' in o, linesForItem))
```

- **`True`** - If there is at least one element in the `linesForItem` list that contains `'ERROR'` substring
- **`False`** - Otherwise

Then just wrap it inside your function like this:

```
def isGood(linesForItem)
    return not any(map(lambda o: 'ERROR' in o, linesForItem))
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that 'ERROR' in embedded in the text string, and that all the items in the list are text strings.  Several ways to do this, here is my favourite:

```
myList = ['stuff', 'xxxxERRORxxxx', '42']

if any([s.find('ERROR') > -1 for s in myList]):
    result = True
else:
    result = False
```

The `find` method returns the position of the start of the string, or -1 if not present.